# After restarting the app, onboarding screen shows again

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

*This is code of onboarding fragment 3.in In this code, I have set on click listener to the floating action button fb and tried to save the state of the button clicked.*

```
public class onBoardinFragment3 extends Fragment {

    FloatingActionButton fab;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_onboarding3, container,false);

        **fab = root.findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);**
                **SharedPreferences prf = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("mypref",MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prf.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("isOpened",true);
                editor.commit();**

            }
        });

        return root;
    }

}
```

> This the code of introductory Activity. The value of
> isIntroductoryOpened doe nor become false after clicking the floating
> button in onboarding fragment 3.

```
public class IntroductoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView BgImage;
    LottieAnimationView lottieAnimationView;

    private static final int Num_Pages = 3;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ScreenSlidePagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    Animation anim;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        **if (isIntroductoryOpened()){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }**


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_introductiory);



        BgImage = findViewById(R.id.bgImage);
        lottieAnimationView = findViewById(R.id.lottie);

        BgImage.animate().translationY(-4000).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(4000);
        lottieAnimationView.animate().translationY(1400).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(4000);



        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.customanim);
        viewPager.startAnimation(anim);



    }

    **private boolean isIntroductoryOpened() {
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean isIntroOpened = pref.getBoolean("isOpened",false);
        return isIntroOpened;
    }**


    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    onBoardinFragment1 tab1 = new onBoardinFragment1();
                    return tab1;
                case 1:
                    onBoardinFragment2 tab2 = new onBoardinFragment2();
                    return tab2;
                case 2:
                    onBoardinFragment3 tab3 = new onBoardinFragment3();

                    return tab3;
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return Num_Pages;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the activity before OnBoarding activity, change the code as:

```
    SharedPreferences onBoarding = getSharedPreferences("onBoardingScreen",MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean isFirstTime = onBoarding.getBoolean("firstTime",true);
    if(isFirstTime){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = onBoarding.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstTime",false);
        editor.commit();

        Intent intent = new Intent(PrevActivity.this,OnBoarding.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else{
        Intent intent = new Intent(PrevActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

PrevActivity is the activity before OnBoarding and NextActivity is the activity after OnBoarding acitivity.
In second line the true value is the default value for `firstTime`, once getting in the `if` block, the value will be set to `false` and the OnBoarding activity will not be shown again to the user.

> This code will come in place of the code you have written for going from PrevActivity to the OnBoarding activity.

Comment: In your code splash screen is not showing properly the second time. when I run the code the first time the app won't run than the second time it redirects me to the main activity but does not show a splash screen or we can the screen on which I animate the logo. I replace the previous activity with IntrosuctoryActivity.this and the next activity with mainactivity.class.

Comment: i am attaching the git link of the updated code https://github.com/sam2001x/code.git